# How can I upload a file to S3 via Powershell with AES256 encryption without installing AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to AWS S3 with AES256 encryption however I am not allowed to install the AWS CLI. I have the code below which allows me to upload files to S3 using my secret keys however this does not work then encryption is required for the S3 bucket. How do I perform something similar to: `aws s3api put-object --server-side-encryption=AES256 --bucket=<bucket_name> --key=<name_of_object_when_uploaded> --body=/<path>/<object_to_upload>` with my code below?

```
    # Config Parts
$_rawfilename = 'C:/<NAME>/SSP00001_RITM1304145.csv'
$folder = 'TestResults'
$filename = $_rawfilename.Split('/')[2]
$keyFile = ($folder+ '/' + $filename)
$service = 's3'
$bucket = '<BUCKET NAME>'
$region = 'us-east-1'
$host1 = $bucket + '.s3'  + '.amazonaws.com'
$access_key = ''
$secret_key = ''
$br = [regex]::Unescape('\u000a')
function HmacSHA256($message, $secret) {
    $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = $secret
    $signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
    return $signature
}

function getSignatureKey($key, $dateStamp, $regionName, $serviceName) {
    $kSecret = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(('AWS4' + $key).toCharArray())
    $kDate = HmacSHA256 $dateStamp $kSecret
    $kRegion = HmacSHA256 $regionName $kDate
    $kService = HmacSHA256 $serviceName $kRegion
    $kSigning = HmacSHA256 'aws4_request' $kService

    return $kSigning
}

function hash($request) {
    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create()
    $content = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($request)
    $bytes = $hasher.ComputeHash($content)
    return ($bytes | ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''
}
function requestBuilder($method, $key) {

    $now = [DateTime]::UtcNow
    $amz_date = $now.ToString('yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ')
    $datestamp = $now.ToString('yyyyMMdd')

    $signed_headers = 'host'
    $credential_scope = $datestamp + '/' + $region + '/' + $service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

    $canonical_querystring = ''
    $canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + [uri]::EscapeDataString(($access_key + '/' + $credential_scope))
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + $amz_date
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=86400'
    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + $signed_headers

    $canonical_headers = 'host:' + $host1 + $br

    $canonical_request = $method + $br
    $canonical_request += '/' + $key + $br
    $canonical_request += $canonical_querystring + $br
    $canonical_request += $canonical_headers + $br
    $canonical_request += $signed_headers + $br
    $canonical_request += 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'

    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'

    $canonical_request_hash = hash -request $canonical_request
    $string_to_sign = $algorithm + $br
    $string_to_sign += $amz_date + $br
    $string_to_sign += $credential_scope + $br
    $string_to_sign += $canonical_request_hash

    $signing_key = getSignatureKey $secret_key $datestamp $region $service
    $signature =  HmacSHA256 -secret $signing_key -message $string_to_sign
    $signature = ($signature|ForEach-Object ToString x2) -join ''

    $canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + $signature

    $request_url = 'http://' + $host1 + '/' + $key + '?' + $canonical_querystring
    Write-Host $request_url
    return $request_url
}

# Where -InFile is Path/to/xlsx
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri (requestBuilder 'PUT' $keyFile) -InFile $_rawfilename
Start-Sleep -s 2
```

I tried adding `$canonical_querystring += '&X-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256'` to the code however it's still not working:

```
$canonical_querystring = ''
$canonical_querystring = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + [uri]::EscapeDataString(($access_key + '/' + $credential_scope))
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + $amz_date
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=86400'
**$canonical_querystring += '&X-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256'**
$canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + $signed_headers
```

Comment: What about aws powershell moudle?did you consider working with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `x-amz-server-side-encryption` header to your request (`$canonical_headers`).

See:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/specifying-s3-encryption.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

Comment: As I read the documentation, you need to provide all 3 of x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-algorithm, x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key, and 
x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5 if you are using your own. If you're using the Amazon provided, you can use x-amz-server-side​-encryption